# 401 Unauthorized response to CORS preflight OPTIONS request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nginx, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a CORS problem with my WebApi in ASP.NET CORE, when I make a HTTP GET request with my Client i a have this error :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://service.staging.domain.com/application-api-staging/account. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://service.staging.domain.com/application-api-staging/account. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed
```

`https://service.staging.domain.com/application-api-staging` is my WebAPI base
`https://client.staging.domain.com` for my web client.

When i check the Firefox console, I have a request & response header below :

Response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2020 14:55:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 61
Connection: keep-alive
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
ETag: W/"3d-nALmWVEo7YlT78MufcqgeUavvX4"
```

Request headers

```
Host: service.staging.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type,tenant
Referer: https://client.staging.domain.com/application/
Origin: https://client.staging.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

In my webAPi startup.cs I configured the CORS:
startup.cs

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

services.AddCors(options => {
  options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
    builder => {
      builder
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins)
```

And in my controller.

accountController.cs

```
[EnableCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins")]
```

When I test with my client web and my WebAPI in local, 
client web -> http://localhost:4200
WebApi -> https://localhost:44354
In this case, I can make the request, no problem... it work

but in the second case :
client web -> http://localhost:4200
WebApi -> https://service.staging.domain.com/application-api-staging
In this case, i have a CORS problem, not work

the same in the third case with the web client and WebApi deploy
client web -> https://client.staging.domain.com/application/
WebApi -> https://service.staging.domain.com/application-api-staging
the same, I have a CORS probleme, not work

Same error see in the beginning from my question for the error message.

Why I have an error CORS with the url staging ? and/or i can fix that ? 
Its a nginx problem ?

thank for your help.

**UPDATE**

The WebAPI and the Webclient work on the Linux Server, so I don't use IIS but I use NGINX.

How I can configure NGINX, or may be it's a asp.net core configuration the problem ?

Comment: The real problem is that the server is responding to the preflight OPTIONS request with a 401 Unauthorized error. You need to configure that server to not require authentication for OPTIONS requests. In other words, you don’t have a CORS problem to fix — you have a 401 problem to fix.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, Thank for your help,  I can fix the problem in the WebAPI or it's problem with a reverse proxy or other ?

Answer (score 13):

Check your middleware usage order in StartUp.cs
UseCors() should come before UseAuthorization()

Answer (score 3):

Try this, worked for me

In launchSettings.json, under iisSettings, set anonymousAuthentication and windowsAuthentication to true.

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8791/",
  "sslPort": 0
}
```

Comment: OMG, you've saved my life. This was the only correct  answer. I've checked for days the CORS configuration again and again and this OPTIONS issue made me crazy. Thank you, whoever you are. If you need something, let's say a bus ticket or so, let me know ;-)

Comment: @Henry.K Actually, I'm looking for a job with visa support in the Netherlands, if you know of any opportunities, let me know. LOL